# Error exception handling python program

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, try-catch

```
print("Welcome to Hangman! Guess the mystery word with less than 6 mistakes!")

words= ['utopian','fairy','tree','monday','blue'] 

while True:
        try:
                i=int(input("Please enter an integer number (0<=number<10) to choose the word in the list: "))
        except ValueError:
                print("Empty input!")
        break
if(words[i]):
        print("The length of the word is: " , len(words[i]))
```

So I was able to catch the value error for my Hangman program that I'm doing so far but then it occurred to me. It doesn't just catch the value error of an empty input but it also catches the value error if someone were to input a non-integer character like an alphabetical letter. I want it to do both, so how can I set up another exception that will print("Please enter an integer!")?

Dammit,I tried fixing the program by adding a few other lines that I came up with for the program and I added a "break" in but when I do that I can't an error stating that "i" is not defined. Now if I take it out and run the program, the loop continues even if the user enters an integer as their input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling errors and exceptions in Hangman python program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576384/handling-errors-and-exceptions-in-hangman-python-program)

Comment: Use isinstance(i, int) to control type error.

Comment: @RobinKrahl it seems that the question you linked is an older version of this question.

Comment: Please `edit` your question in future, instead of posting another question which is just an updated version of an older one

Comment: @minerz029 okay, it did not know that this is possible! feel free to do that. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Welcome to Hangman! Guess the mystery word with less than 6 mistakes!")

words= ['utopian','fairy','tree','monday','blue'] 

while True:
    i=input("Please enter an integer number (0<=number<10) to choose the word in the list: ")

    if i in (None, ""):
        print("Null input")
        continue

    try:
        i = int(i)
    except ValueError:
        print("Not valid integer")
        continue
    else:
        if not 0 <= i < 10:
            print("not in valid range of 0<=number<10")
            continue

    break

print("You have entered", i)
print("The word you have chosen is {} letters long".format(words[i]))
```

The `input()` function returns a string. Blatantly converting that to `int()` right away may not be the right course of action if you want to perform more checks first. This first checks if it is an empty string, then if it is an integer by trying to convert it to `int()`, then checks if this integer is in the valid range. At the end of this, the valid integer `i` is left over.

Comment: Even if I put in a proper integer I get "Not an integer!"

Comment: @user2901609 see the new version